# HELP! ASSEMBLER FASM

Tags: ассемблер, методы, ос, fasm, binary-file

Крч, мне нужно сделать ОС. У меня есть файл main.asm и с помощью команды fasm main.asm boot.bin
все компилируется. НО мне нужно еще один файл запихнуть в boot.bin. Как такое сделать??

P. S. А как вызвать процедуру одного файла из другого??

Comment: Делайте include второго файла в первом. Это ответ на оба вопроса. Если нужно вставить файл как бинарный блок в asm файл, то можно использовать директиву file, например `file 'somefile.bin'` - к этим данным можно будет обращаться по метке (см. [Data definitions](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.2))

Comment: а incbin не подойдет? Или он не для Fasm?

Comment: Нет, в fasm нет такой директивы. Я привел ссылку на документацию.

Comment: спасибо большое